# Pass element to parent component after output child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I just output something from a child component and I was wondering how I can pass along an element from the parent template to the parent component after this.

Normally I make a variable of the element (#textArea in this case), but somehow I can't pass it along. Does someone know how this is done?

**Parent template: editReview($event, textArea) is the function that gets sent from the child component. I receive the $event part in my editReview fucntion, but not the element reference.**

```
<app-review-list [movie]="movie" (editReview)="editReview($event, textArea)"></app-review-list>

    <hr>

    <form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="review">Write A Review:</label>
            <textarea
                    #textArea
                    (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(f)"
                    rows="4"
                    cols="50"
                    type="text"
                    id="review"
                    ngModel
                    class="form-control"
                    name="review"
                    required
            ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onClear(f)">Clear</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

**This is the parent component. In the editReview method, console.log(content) gives me the result I desired, but the other console.log gives me nothing**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {ReviewService} from "./review.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
    selector: 'app-review',
    templateUrl: './review.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./review.component.css']
})

export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit{

    movieId;
    @Input('movie') movie;


    constructor(private reviewService: ReviewService, private route: ActivatedRoute){}


    editReview(content, elem){
        console.log(content);
        console.log(elem)
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the template? The one case I see where the template reference variable will not be defined in the event handler is if the variable is declared inside a structure directive like `ngIf` or `ngFor`. So, if the textArea is inside such a directive, the variable will not be defined outside of the directive. As for the code in your question, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with passing a `temple reference variable` into a method if that template reference variable is set on an element that is anywhere within a structural directive (such as an `*ngIf`).

If in your actual code (not the posted snippet) you have a structural directive, that explains the issue. If you don't, it is not clear why it is not working.

In either case, another way to do it is with the ViewChild decorator.

**Parent component**

In the parent component, add the following declaration:

```
@ViewChild('textArea') myElementRef: ElementRef;
```

And modify the `editReview` method as follows:

```
editReview(content){
    console.log(content);
    console.log(this.myElementRef);
}
```

Comment: You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-6uatu2) that passing template reference variables to a method does work. The case that fails in the example is for the variable declared in the `ngIf` directive; I assume that the variable is defined only in the scope of that directive.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it in my app before I posted and it didn't work there either.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce your case in a stackblitz? Except for variables declared in structural directives, which are not visible outside of the directive scope, I am under the impression that it should work (and I hope it does because I sometimes use that technique in my code).

Comment: Yea, I thought that it should work and was surprised when it didn't. I just went back and retried it paying more close attention to where I put the template reference variable ... and you are correct. If it is anywhere within an *ngIf ... it does not work. Seems like it may be a bug? Thank you for catching this and I'll update my answer with this additional info.

Comment: I think that the scope of template reference variable is designed to be limited to the inner template (`ngIf` and `ngFor` are implemented as templates). It allows to use a variable inside an `ngFor` loop for example, knowing that it refers to a specific instance of the element. It would make no sense for the variable to be visible outside of the directive in that case.